# UIImagePickerController Crash in iOS 10.3 when Selecting Video

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

So I'm doing the very simple Image Picker that I've written hundreds of times. For that I wrote this very simple Extension:

```
extension UIImagePickerController {

    func present(over controller: UIViewController,
                 with source: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType,
                 mediaTypes: [String]? = nil) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.allowsEditing = true
            self.sourceType = source
            if source == .camera {
                self.cameraDevice = .front
            }
            self.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            self.mediaTypes = mediaTypes ?? UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: source) ?? []
            controller.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. That is of course until you select a video.
As soon as you select a video I get this beauty of a stack trace:

[image: BEAUTIFUL!!!!!]

And before you ask. Yeah I've set up all the privacy settings in my Info.plist:

NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
NSCameraUsageDescription

Could this be a Beta issue in 10.3? I hope so ;) **Nope**

**EDIT:** I managed to test this on another device and it doesn't have anything to do with the beta.

So far my best contenders are:

- I screwed something up (big possibility)
- Something else (a dependency, maybe) is registering for the wrong notification

Comment: Well, the easy way to find out if it's a 10.3 issue is to try it on something running a non-beta iOS version. Are you able to?

Comment: @dfd not without a downgrade. I only have one device at hand. And I want it on the beta to use Swift 3.1... I just wanted to see if anyone had this issue before going through downgrading and later upgrading again ;)

Comment: I managed to get a friend to test it and it isn't beta related...

Comment: Well, the good news is twofold - you know you can rule 10.3 out, and you *probably* can debug this on your device. My suggestion is back out of things on your extension... and slowly add them back in. (Possibly even start without the override.) I personally don't use *Dispatch* much at all so that would be my first focus. Stupid question... are you trying to do something UI related there on a background thread? I wish you luck.

Comment: I fixed this issue. Had nothing to do with my code. Someone else decided to log all Notifications. Which screwed everything up

Answer (score 1):

After Hours and Hours I found the issue. Turns out someone in the project thought it would be a good idea to write this:

```
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: nil,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil) { note in

                // Some strange code we were not using anymore
                // Mainly logging all activity made as Notifications
        }
```

He just wanted more logs.
Which seems to mess with:

- some C++ exceptions within AVPlayer
- fetching local AVAssets with a URL

Thanks a lot anyways ;)

It's time to put Git Blame into use!